# Finding the difference between two rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having trouble finding the difference between two rows. I've checked out different pandas functions like pd.diff, but those don't work on what I want it to. That's for numeric data. I'm trying to build a function that works regardless of the type of the data.

Here's my sample df:

```
employee = ['John', 'Jill', 'Jeremy', 'Julie', "Jacob"]
sex = ["Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male"]
cars_sold = [3, 5, 4, 3, 6]
top_model = ["Accord", "Accord", "Civic", "CR-V", "Odyssey"]
hiring_mgr = ["Paul", "Paul", "Patricia", "Patricia", "Patty"]
years_company = [7, 2, 4, 4, 11]
personal_car = ["Accord", "Sierra", "Mustang", "Accord", "CX-5"]


data = {'Employee Name': employee, 'Sex': sex, '# Cars Sold': cars_sold, "Top Selling Model": top_model,
        'Hiring Manager': hiring_mgr, 'Years With Company': years_company, 'Personal Car': personal_car}
column_names = data.keys()

#turning it into a df
cars = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

#showing the df
cars
```

[image]

Here's the function I'm trying to create:

```
def sim_func(df, row1, row2):
    for col1, col2 in zip(df.loc[df['Employee Name'] == row1].columns, df.loc[df['Employee Name'] == row2].columns):
        if df.loc[df['Employee Name'] == row1][col1] == df.loc[df['Employee Name'] == row2][col1]:
            print(col1)
            
sim_func(cars, 'John', 'Jill')
```

It's resulting in an error of:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-8d5f031d82cf> in <module>
      6             print(col1)
      7 
----> 8 sim_func(cars, 'John', 'Jill')

<ipython-input-18-8d5f031d82cf> in sim_func(df, row1, row2)
      3 def sim_func(df, row1, row2):
      4     for col1, col2 in zip(df.loc[df['Employee Name'] == row1].columns, df.loc[df['Employee Name'] == row2].columns):
----> 5         if df.loc[df['Employee Name'] == row1][col1] != df.loc[df['Employee Name'] == row2][col1]:
      6             print(col1)
      7 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py in wrapper(self, other, axis)
   1140 
   1141         elif isinstance(other, ABCSeries) and not self._indexed_same(other):
-> 1142             raise ValueError("Can only compare identically-labeled " "Series objects")
   1143 
   1144         elif is_categorical_dtype(self):

ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

My desired outcome based from this example is: "Employee Name", "Sex", "# Cars Sold", "Years With Company", "Personal Car" or something to that effect.

I appreciate your help.

Comment: "I'm trying to build a function that works regardless of the type of the data" Can you please [edit] to include your expected output? `difference` has many different connotations depending on the context. Are you trying to output 1/some/all columns where the data for one employee just doesn't match that for the other employee, or what?

Comment: I'm not understanding well your question, you did not make your point very clear. However, you can use set's `difference` method to get the difference between two sequences, i.e, columns or rows

Comment: My expected output is at the end of the document. In other words, I'm trying to find every column where the two rows don't have the same information.

Comment: I've never used/heard of df.duplicated @user19077881 From googling it, it looks like I'm trying to do the complete opposite. I want to see what's *not* duplicated. I'm looking at the syntax now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the function use `sim_func(cars, 'John', 'Jill')` and your function definition it looks like the row selection has to be done along the column `Employee Name`. Now, under the assumption that the items in this column are unique, you could modify your function in the following way:

```py
def sim_func(df, row1, row2):
    df1 = df[df['Employee Name'] == row1]
    df2 = df[df['Employee Name'] == row2]
    for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
        if df1.iat[0, i] != df2.iat[0, i]:
            print(col)
```

The result for `sim_func(cars, 'John', 'Jill')` would be:

```
Employee Name
Sex
# Cars Sold
Years With Company
Personal Car
```

Besides avoiding redoing a lot of stuff (e.g. you do `df['Employee Name'] == row1/2` a lot of times, instead of just once) this avoids the source of your problem: index alignment. You are actually comparing two series which both have different indices, and for comparision (and a lot of other uses) indices are aligned. You can see this if you do

```py
print(cars.loc[cars['Employee Name'] == 'Jill']['Sex'])
print(cars.loc[cars['Employee Name'] == 'John']['Sex'])
```

and get

```
1    Female
Name: Sex, dtype: object
0    Male
Name: Sex, dtype: object
```

If there's a chance that the names aren't unique then you could switch to something like

```py
def sim_func(df, row1, row2):
    sub_df = df[df['Employee Name'].isin([row1, row2])]
    for col in df.columns:
        if sub_df[col].nunique(dropna=False) > 1:
            print(col)
```

or

```py
def sim_func(df, row1, row2):
    count = df[df['Employee Name'].isin([row1, row2])].nunique(axis=0, dropna=False)
    for col in count[count > 1].index:
        print(col)
```

both using `.nunique()` to check if there's more than one item in a column.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the columns that have mismatches as follows:

```py
columns_with_mismatch = df.columns[(YOURROW != YOUROTHERROW).tolist()]
```

And then

```py
mismatch_dataframe = df[columns_with_mismatch]
```